# Shopify social login buttons

Tags: shopify

I’m trying to build a social login button app for Shopify that shows up on the login page. I’m unable to find any documentation online to get started with this, I’ll appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction for resources on this.

Comment: The proper way is to use multipass, which is available only for Shopify Plus. If not there are only sketchy workarounds.